# Express Validator: Destruction of nested object is painful - is there a better way?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using nodejs/mongoDB/mongoose/express-validator and I am trying to output the error-messages via validationResult(req). It's my understanding that this returns a nested object which I then have to destruct in order to access the messages.

**Edit**: It's express-validator version 4.x (Sept 2017) which is why I cannot find better documentation/tutorials ... all the current available tuts refer to methods which won't work anymore.

```
app.post("/register",
check("username").isEmail().withMessage("Ungültige E-Mailadresse"),
check("password").isLength({ min: 4 }).withMessage("Ungültiges Passwort"),
check("password").equals("password-repeat").withMessage("Passwort stimmt nicht überein"),
function (req, res) {
    var errors = validationResult(req).mapped();
    if (errors) {
        try {
            var { username: { msg: username_error } } = errors;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Undefined shit u so");
        }
        try {
            var { password: { msg: password_error } } = errors;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Undefined shit u so");
        }
        var messages = [username_error, password_error];
        res.render("register", {
            title: "Register",
            errors: messages
        })
    } else {
        res.redirect("/register");
    }
})
```

The above code works but is a pain ... If I don't try/catch every possible TypeError (cannot destruct undefined or null), nodejs crashes.

Is there a better way to create an array with only existing error-messages?

Thanks!
Philip

Comment: You could use `if` statements to test what is there rather than letting it throw exceptions that you have to catch.

Comment: Thanks - but from my POV that would result in the same... I'd have to write a statement for every possible error-message. What do you think?

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you're expecting.  You can use one try/catch around all of it to catch any error or you can test each individual one with an `if`.  Those are your two choices.

Comment: I wanted to know wether there is a possibility to catch only the msg-values inside nested objects and put them in an array to iterate over it. My bad! I wasn't clear. Would you know a way to accomplish this? Thx

Comment: Well,, you can use `Object.keys(obj)` on any object and that will get a list of the enumerable properties that are present and you can then iterate over them.  Or if what you're trying to do is more complicated than that, you can write a little utility function to grab an array of whatever you want out of any complicated structure.  If you showed an example of what `errors` looks like (what things are sometimes there and sometimes not there), it would make offering a more specific idea easier.

Comment: express-validator maintainer here. _"all the current available tuts refer to methods which won't work anymore"_ -- while the legacy methods are, well, legacy, they still work. You can still use them, although I advise against it, as they'll go away in some major release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want to check for errors existence then you have to use [.isEmpty()](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#isempty) method:

```
var errors = validationResult(req);

if ( errors.isEmpty() ) {
    res.redirect("/register");
} else {
    // send validation messages
}
```

From your code above, it seems that you are looking for changing the errors object into array of messages to show them in the view. another way consists of sending the mapped object to your view and then check for errors existence based on field names, here is an example:

**route handler:**

```
var errors = validationResult(req);

if ( errors.isEmpty() ) {
    res.redirect("/register");
} else {
    res.render("register", {
        title: "Register",
        errors: errors.mapped();
    });
}
```

**View** (example using ejs view engine)

```
<div>
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <!-- check if there is any errors related to username input -->
    <% if ( errors.hasOwnProperty('username') ) { %>
        <span class="error"> <%= errors.username.msg %> </span>
    <% } %>
</div>

<div>
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <!-- check if there is any errors related to username input -->
    <% if ( errors.hasOwnProperty('password') ) { %>
        <span class="error"> <%= errors.password.msg %> </span>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Remember that the `mapped()` method return an object where the keys are the field names, and the values are the validation errors

**EDIT** If you want to render errors as array then use [.array()](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#arrayoptions) method:

```
res.render("register", {
    title: "Register",
    errors: errors.array({ onlyFirstError: true });
});
```

You can then iterate over the array of errors from the view and show all errors in a list, for example:

```
<ul>
    <% for ( var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++ ) { %>
        <li>field: <%= errors[i].param %>, Error message: <%= errors[i].msg %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That worked very well - thanks! Would there be a possibility of checking for "msg"-properties and output them in a new array so I could iterate over it instead of templating every possible error-message? Thanks!

Comment: @FÖLA, I edited my answer, please take a look, consider [marking my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it works for you, and also for future readers

Comment: thanks a thousand times! Thats exactly was I was looking for :-)